# LyX start every time as a new application

Tags: applications

I use LyX and I installed last version 2.3.5.2 on macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Whenever I launch the application the system shows a progress bar saying 'Verifico "Lyx.app"...' (this is Italian, in English it should read something like 'Verifying "Lyx.app"...' or 'Checking "Lyx.app"...').

After that a window pops-up saying '"Lyx.app" è un'applicazione scaricata da internet. Confermi di volerla aprire?' (that translated is '"Lyx.app" is an application downloaded from internet. Do you confirm you want to open it?'), and I answer "yes".

This behavior is OK for the first run, but it repeats every time I launch the application, and seems more a problem of macOS than a problem of Lyx. Can someone help?

Comment: How and where did you install LyX? Did you copy it to /Applications?

Comment: It is a .dmg file, and once opened it ask to drag the app in /Applications @nohillside

Comment: And did you drag it and now run it from /Applications, or do you start it directly from the .DMG?

Comment: @nohillside I dragged it in /Applications, unmounted the .dmg and I run it from /Applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realized that the folder `/Applications/LyX.app/` didn't have write permissions not even for the proprietary user, differently from all other `*.app` folders in `/Applications`, so the execution of the command

```
chmod +w /Applications/LyX.app
```

solved the problem.